# Why is my code printing symbols instead of letters?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am supposed to write a program with three files (mysource.c, myMain.c, and mysource.h) to create a randomly generated string of characters. The length of the string is decided by the user. After the string is generated, the program will bump all letters in the string to the next letter in the alphabet to create a new offset string. I have most of the code sorted out, but my output is printing "╠╠╠╠". It prints the correct amount of characters but it is only printing those symbols. What do I need to do so that the characters print as actual letters rather than these symbols?

Here is my header file:

```
void generateChars(char *myarr, int len);
void offsetChars(char *myarr, int len);
void printChars(char *myarr, int len);
```

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mysource.h"

void generateChars(char* myarr, int len)
{
    int i = 0;

    char letters[26] ={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o' 
,'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++);
    {
        myarr[i] = letters[rand() % 26];
    }
}
//end generate function

void offsetChars(char *myarr, int len)
{
char i;
int j;

for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
{
    for (i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
    {
        if (myarr[j] == i)
        {
            myarr[j] = i + 1;
            break;
        }
        if (myarr[j] == 'z')
        {
            myarr[j] = 'a';
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
   //end offset function

  void printChars(char *myarr, int len)
 {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
     printf("%c",myarr[i]);
 }
 }//end of print function
```

Here is my main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mysource.h"

int main()
{
int n;

printf("How many random characters do you want to 
generate?: ");
scanf_s("%i", &n);

char myarr[1024];
printf("\nOriginal Combo:\n");

generateChars(&myarr, n);
printChars(&myarr, n);

printf("\nOffset Combo:\n");
offsetChars(&myarr, n);
printChars(&myarr, n);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I get:

[I don't have enough reputation so this is the picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRYCV.png)

Yes there are two source codes, the objective is to make this assignment work with both source codes. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < len; i++);` This is a loop with an empty body, doing nothing. `{ myarr[i] = letters[rand() % 26]; }` This runs once, at the end of the aforementioned loop, assigning to `myarr[len]` which is never used.

Comment: So how could I go about getting that loop to run? I feel like the answer is very simple but I really can't seem to figure this out. I figure my rand function is messing up somehow. Am I doing something wrong with that?

Comment: Removing that stray semicolon would be a good start.

Comment: I removed the semicolon, but the loop has a body, that's where the random character gets generated, for the user chosen length of the array. I'm pretty sure the random function is doing something unexpected.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < len; i++);` (note the semicolon) is equivalent to `for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {}` - a loop with an empty body.

Comment: Ah, I knew I was overlooking something very simple. That loop is now fixed, but I am having another issue with the print function. Now when the program runs, it prints forever. Probably something simple again but it helps having others look at it. Thanks!

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/qGTfvYeKe)

Comment: Thanks I guess.